Stuck in GNU Grub
I've been using Ubuntu 22.04 for a month now. All of a sudden when I boot up I'm stuck in GNU Grub version 2.06. I have Windows and Ubuntu dual booted on my laptop, and it's worked fine until today. Exit does work and gets me on Windows, but I want to access Ubuntu. I tried to follow a tutorial online, but I can't seem to find the path to my
Ubuntu partition as my Windows hard drive is Apparently (hd0) and (hd1) doesn't have any accessible partitions.
When I try to list hard drive partitions:


From the photo, I can't tell that hd1 has no accessible partitions. Doesn't it?

if i type in ls (hd1) is says the file system isn't recognized

The only solution I know of is to create a USB "repair-disk".... https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair-cd/home/Home/   ---  It's straightforward and quick. Also see: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair   .... Cheers !
